# Can't install GNOME extensions on Ubuntu 18.10 using Firefox

Tags: firefox, gnome-shell, 18.10, gnome-shell-extension

I wanted to install GSConnect to transfer a file from my phone to my laptop. So I installed

```
sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell
```

Then I installed the Firefox addon from the GNOME extensions website. However, when I click on the switch to enable the extension it prompts me to install the extension but the extension does not install and when I refresh the page the slider is back to off.

I reset my configs with:

```
dconf reset -f /
```

Debugging the Firefox addon tells me this:

```
Unchecked lastError value: Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

I also tried to install the extension manually but it didn't work either.

It's not just this gsconnect, I can't enable/disable other extensions either. I have the same issue in chrome.

Comment: Is this happening only with this specific extension? Or all extensions? What happens if you use the *Software* application instead (refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1029306/480481))?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: After changing file ownership to my current user for ~/.local (recursively) it was fixed. You might also have to reset gnome-settings using `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/`

Thanks to the link provided by @[pomsky](https://askubuntu.com/users/480481/pomsky) I learned that you could install extensions from the software center on Ubuntu. When I tried to do this I got an error. It was something along the lines of "shell.extractExtensionError".

The first suggestion to this problem suggested me to reset gnome settings with `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/`. After rebooting the issue was still present.

After some digging I learned that you could get more information about what was going wrong by running the command `sudo journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-shell`

There were a lot of errors related to opening files, so I ran `sudo chown -R $USER ~/.local` and this fixed the problem.